# Получение DES-ключа из пароля пользователя в OpenSSL

Tags: c, криптография

Подскажите, как в OpenSSL получается ключ для DES (или для 3-DES, не суть) из пароля пользователя? Смотрю исходники, но глаз уже "замылился". В какой функции какого исходника это написано?

Comment: А он должен получаться из пароля пользователя? Интересно. В kerberos такая канитель была, а насчёт openssl как-то сомнение берёт.

Comment: Ну по идее должен. Он ещё подсаливается, вроде...Я, канЭшн, как время будет и голова свежая ещё раз залезу в исходники, крутая тема для диплома может выйти, не правда ли?